# Scrolling focus with combo box Tab control in C# winapplication

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

After you click outside the drop down, it seems the focus is still on the drop down; scrolling, you select (without knowing) another value.

I want to lose the focus while clicking on the tab control or any location of the page.

Comment: So? What is your question? It is by design, you have to get the focus on another control to lose the focus on the `dropDown`. Clicking on the form will indeed not lose the focus on the `dropDown`.

Comment: thx..for reply...i want to lose the focus while click on tab control or any location of page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Otiel commented, click outside `ComboBox` won't make it lose the focus. 
You can handle the `Click` event for the container (eg. a `Panel`) of your `ComboBox` and set the `Focus` to other control by using [Control.Focus Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.focus.aspx).